# Running query to find time difference

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have some devices sending power status to Azure Log Analytics workspace.
If the Power is UP it sends AC_UP alert and if it's down the alter is AC_Down. 
Each log analytics log contains timestamp, hostname, networkname and status.

I want to able to run a query so that I can find the following.
1. Run the query and search for AC_Down alert. Take each hostname and search for AC_UP for the time after the AC_Down alert. Calculate the time difference between Down and Up and the result should show the following.
Hostname, Time difference, network name

Here are some logs.

```
2019-07-17T12:15:21.493         LocationA   DeviceA AC_UP   2019-07-17T17:45:21.349 powerAlerts_CL      203a6c7d-48b7-415e-b5d3-67e815813aaf    RestAPI         
2019-07-17T12:17:07.294         LocationB   DeviceX AC_UP   2019-07-17T17:47:05.524 powerAlerts_CL      203a6c7d-48b7-415e-b5d3-67e815813aaf    RestAPI         
2019-07-17T12:28:27.321         LocationA   DeviceA AC_Down 2019-07-17T17:58:24.142 powerAlerts_CL      203a6c7d-48b7-415e-b5d3-67e815813aaf    RestAPI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each device  conducts only one session at a time, we can try to match each start event with next stop event of the same device.

```
PowerAlerts_CL
| where Status == "AC_UP"
| project Location , Device ,StartTime = timestamp
| join kind= inner
   (PowerAlerts_CL
    | where status == "AC_Down"
    | project Stoptime = timestamp , Device)
    on Device
| extend duration = StopTime-StartTime
| where duration>0
| summarize arg_min(duration,*) by bin(StartTime,1s),Device
```

arg_min picks out the row with the smallest duration in each group, and the * parameter passes through all the other columns, though it prefixes "min_" to each column name.